# How to display a code of conduct/rules of use upon user login

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp

Back at the after school volunteer project, we want to add a little dialog with Code of conduct/rules of user which the user must click through when they logon.

How do you do this?  Whats the easiest what?

We are using Windows Server 2003 with Active Directory and all the clients are XP.

The students all have their own accounts, although there are a few generic accounts for people who occasionally use the facilities...

Thanks in advance for any ideas/tips etc.
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set this in group policy. To set this you want to open up group policy management console (if you don't have it you can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a6d4c24-8cbd-4b35-9272-dd3cbfc81887)) Your best bet is to set this on the default domain policy, right click then edit. in the policy go to:

Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies/Security Options -> Interactive Logon -> Interactive logon: Message Text for users attempting to log on

You can set your prompt there, also there will be an item "Interactive Logon: Message title for users attempting to logon" you can set an informative title for the message box there.

Comment: Thanks - we have a Default Domain User Policy with user configuration, tried adding it there to no avail.  I created a new policy just for this at the same level and that worked great.